# jQuery, AJAX: Pop up jQuery dialog with passed parameter to html form

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, parameter-passing, jquery-dialog

I can pop up a jQuery dialog with an empty html form.

But now, I'd like to pop up a jQuery dialog with an html form that has passed parameters.

Code:

button that triggers jQuery dialog (JSP code):

```
<input id="update_button" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="UpdateFunction('<%=category.getTag()%>');" />
```

script that is for dialog:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function UpdateFunction(tag) {
            alert(tag); // I can get this parameter correctly
            $( "#update_category" ).dialog( "open" );
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#update_category" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

HTML form code (it involves GAE code originally in "form action", and I've removed it to make this question clear):

```
<body>
    <%
        String categoryTag = request.getParameter("categoryTag");
        // curCategory will be derived from categoryTag
    %>
    <div id="update_category">
        <form id="categoryForm" name="categoryForm">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tag : </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="categoryTag" style="color:#888;" value="<%= curCategory.getTag() %>" readonly /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Title : </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="categoryTitle" value="<%=  curCategory.getTitle() %>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

The question is:

Currently, the code in body will be executed at first, so that "String categoryTag" will get null in the following

```
<%
    String categoryTag = request.getParameter("categoryTag");
    // curCategory will be derived from categoryTag
%>
```

And it will result in NullPointerException later.

So how I can pop up a jQuery dialog with passed parameter form?

Thanks in advance.

Eric

Comment: If i understand you correctly , you need to pass the dynamic values to  the dialog ?

Comment: @san krish  yes, I need to pass dynamic values to the dialog

Comment: Why dont you trigger the function on click so that the form will be loaded with dynamic values

Comment: @san krish  How I can load form dynamically when dialog open?

Comment: i mean open the dialog , only when you have values in the form . so trigger it on click

Comment: @san krish  I know, but how I can do that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the separate `.dialog( "open" )` function . you can write it as ,

```
<script>
        function UpdateFunction(tag) {
            alert(tag); // I can get this parameter correctly
            var dialog_text=tag;
            $("#update_category").empty();
            $("#update_category").append(dialog_text);
            $( "#update_category" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600 
                //Handle your button events for the dialog.
            });
        }
    </script>
```